# Algorithm for converting from projected coordinate system to geographic one using Helmert transformation

Tags: coordinate-system, algorithm, datum

I have a data in projected coordinates system and I need to convert them to WGS84. I know the parameters of position vector transformation and I know the projection details of my projected coordinate system.

I think I need firstly transform my projected points to geographic one and secondly use Helmert transformation to transform between geographic coordinates.

I think I need to use my projection details for projected system to transform it into geographic, but I am completely helpless with it.

I am looking for algorithm, I mean some code or pseudo code, not for a software, since I wish to implement this later in javascript.

Here is what I've got.

If I may borrow Helmert transformation function from the accepted answer to this post ([What is the process to calculate Helmert parameters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84449/what-is-the-process-to-calculate-helmert-parameters)), my position vector details are:

```
#displacement in meters
c0 = c(485.000000,169.500000,483.800000)
#rotation in arcseconds
r=c(7.786000,4.398000,4.103000)
#scale in ppm
s=0.000000
```

And my projected system details are:

> S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North WKID: 5514 Authority: EPSG
>
> Projection: Krovak False_Easting: 0.0 False_Northing: 0.0
>   Pseudo_Standard_Parallel_1: 78.5 Scale_Factor: 0.9999 Azimuth:
>   30.28813975277778 Longitude_Of_Center: 24.83333333333333 Latitude_Of_Center: 49.5 X_Scale: -1.0 Y_Scale: 1.0 XY_Plane_Rotation:
>   90.0 Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)
>
> Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_S_JTSK Angular Unit: Degree
>   (0.0174532925199433) Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0) Datum: D_S_JTSK
>   Spheroid: Bessel_1841
>       Semimajor Axis: 6377397.155
>       Semiminor Axis: 6356078.962818189
>       Inverse Flattening: 299.1528128

Comment: The math for both is available in the IOGP (EPSG) [Guidance Note 7-2](http://www.epsg.org/Guidancenotes.aspx).

Comment: @mkennedy that material looks awesome, thank you for pointing me to this.